# animation with infinite scrollView

Tags: iphone, animation, uiscrollview

I have 5 pictures inside an infinite scrollView.

So in order to make that `scrollView` infinite/circular I positioned my images like this:

5 1 2 3 4 5 1
meaning: last picture first picture second picture.....last picture first picture

And in order for it to become infinite I have the following code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0){

    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*pathImages.count, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) animated:NO];  
        }
    else if (self.scrollView.contentOffset.x == self.view.frame.size.width*(pathImages.count+1)) {         

    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width,0 ,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) animated:NO];    
    }
}
```

which means that when I'm at the last picture the `contentOffset` of the `scrollView` is set to go to the first picture-in this way I get an infinite `scrollView.`

```
  What I wanted next was for my scrollView to slide automatically-for this I set a timer which calls one method-onTimer:

- (void) onTimer{
    NSLog(@"flip pages");
    if(h < pathImages.count*self.view.frame.size.width)
    {
        h+= self.view.frame.size.width;

    }
    else
    {
        h=self.view.frame.size.width;
    }

    if(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0){

        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*pathImages.count, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) animated:NO];  

    }

    if (self.scrollView.contentOffset.x == self.view.frame.size.width*pathImages.count)         

    {      

        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width,0 ,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) animated:NO];                         

    }

    else

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 
                          delay:0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
                     animations:^{ self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(h, 0); } 
                     completion:NULL];
}
```

This magic line:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 
                              delay:0 
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
                         animations:^{ self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(h, 0); } 
                         completion:NULL];
```

does the scoll automatically with animation.

Everything is great except this:

after I view the last picture I should set the offset of scroll view in order to get back to the first picture with animation.

Well if I do that:

```
if (self.scrollView.contentOffset.x == self.view.frame.size.width*pathImages.count)         
            {      
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 
                                  delay:0 
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
                             animations:^{     [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width,0 ,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) animated:NO];  } 
                             completion:NULL];                        

        }
```

after the last picture is viewed in order to get to the first picture...it loops through all the other pictures.

What I want is this:after I view the last picture to get me back to the first picture which should be loaded on screen using animation, but without viewing all the other pictures between them.Thanks

Comment: As a side-note, if this is not something that the user interacts with by scrolling, and instead that you are always automatically animating it, you should not be using a UIScrollView, and instead should handle this simply by animating UIImageViews.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I see this correctly, the problem is, that you again use the animation to scroll the view back to zero position. I believe you need to modify the last bit of code you posted to something like this:

```
if (self.scrollView.contentOffset.x == self.view.frame.size.width*pathImages.count)         
            {      
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width,0 ,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) animated:NO];//no animation on returning
[self onTimer];//even if this code is already inside method "onTimer"
        }
```

Rather then what you are doing try using a scrollview that displays only 3 to 5 images at the time (if they are fullscreen). If you will have many images in your application, it will crash because of high memory consumption. Try playing with this test example that does nearly what you want:

HEADER:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface IScrollView : UIScrollView <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray *imagePaths;
    UIImageView *imageViews[3];
    NSInteger currentImage;
    NSTimer *animationTimer;//weak link
}
@end
```

SOURCE:

```
#import "IScrollView.h"

@implementation IScrollView
- (UIImage *)imageFromResourcesWithName:(NSString *)name {
    UIImage *ret = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:name]];
    return [ret autorelease];
}
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        imagePaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [imagePaths addObject:@"imag1.png"];
        [imagePaths addObject:@"imag2.png"];
        [imagePaths addObject:@"imag3.png"];
        [imagePaths addObject:@"imag4.png"];
        [imagePaths addObject:@"imag5.png"];
        imageViews[0] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320.0f*0, .0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
        imageViews[1] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320.0f*1, .0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
        imageViews[2] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320.0f*2, .0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
        [self addSubview:imageViews[0]];
        [self addSubview:imageViews[1]];
        [self addSubview:imageViews[2]];
        imageViews[0].image = [self imageFromResourcesWithName:[imagePaths objectAtIndex:0]];
        imageViews[1].image = [self imageFromResourcesWithName:[imagePaths objectAtIndex:1]];
        imageViews[2].image = [self imageFromResourcesWithName:[imagePaths objectAtIndex:2]];
        currentImage = 1;
        self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(320.0f*currentImage, .0f);
        self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(3.0f*320.0f, 480.0f);
        self.delegate = self;
        animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/60.0 target:self selector:@selector(scrollFragment) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)repositionIfNeeded {
    CGFloat offsetX = self.contentOffset.x;
    NSInteger iCount = [imagePaths count];
    if(offsetX > 320.0f*1.75f) {
        self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(offsetX-320.0f, .0f);
        imageViews[0].image = imageViews[1].image;
        imageViews[1].image = imageViews[2].image;
        NSInteger imageToLoad = currentImage+2;
        if(imageToLoad>iCount-1)
            imageToLoad -= iCount;
        imageViews[2].image = [self imageFromResourcesWithName:[imagePaths objectAtIndex:imageToLoad]];
        currentImage++;
        if(currentImage>iCount-1)
            currentImage -= iCount;
    }
    else if(offsetX < 320.0f*.25f) {
        self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(offsetX+320.0f, .0f);
        imageViews[2].image = imageViews[1].image;
        imageViews[1].image = imageViews[0].image;
        NSInteger imageToLoad = currentImage-2;
        if(imageToLoad<0)
            imageToLoad += iCount;
        imageViews[0].image = [self imageFromResourcesWithName:[imagePaths objectAtIndex:imageToLoad]];
        currentImage--;
        if(currentImage<0)
            currentImage += iCount;
    }
}
- (void)scrollFragment {
    self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.contentOffset.x+1.0, .0f);
    [self repositionIfNeeded];
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self repositionIfNeeded];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [imageViews[0] release];
    [imageViews[1] release];
    [imageViews[2] release];
    [imagePaths release];
}
@end
```

Comment: what is this going to change/?

Comment: You wrote: "What I want is this:after I view the last picture to get me back to the first picture which should be loaded on screen using animation, but without viewing all the other pictures between them."
You are animating your return to 1st picture for 1 second in your code. By removing that, it will return instantly and you will not see it, then animating forward from beginning..

Comment: Yes my friend......but I want also to move from the last picture to the first one with animation...but without to see the pictures between them.The sliding between the picture1,2.....until the last is done with animation....so that's why I must move from the last picture to the first one using animation.In the way I use animation at the moment when I move from last to first pic...it shows the intermediate pictures and I don't want that.Thank you and please help me:)

Comment: Consider you are near the boarder and there are last 2 images displayed as "5, 1" and nothing follows. What you need to do now is change the position of the scroolview, so it shows the first 2 images as "5, 1" WITHOUT animation and then continue animation. That is what the code above in the "if" statement should solve. The first line repositions the scrollview in the way you should see no difference and then calls [self onTimer]; that continues animation from 5,1 to 1,2.
Anyway, it really depends on what are you doing, but this is not a good way to do a infinite scrollview. RAM problem...

Comment: I've done my infinite scrollView well....but the animation between the edges is what bothers me.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not know how to be more clear on the solution or I just can not understand your question/problem. If I look at your code, it seems that your problem when coming to the border (last image) is that it seems your scrollview is animating its return to the first and you can see all the other images in-between. That is because you need to move the scrollview back to the first image without animating and then call animate again. Now if that is true, the solution should be in my first post, if not please explain what is the problem. And btw, did you even try that solution?

Comment: yes....the first solution and a little bit of the second one solved my problem!:)

Comment: you will receive the 50 reputation also>Thank you:)